# Android M permission dialog not getting dismissed on the click of "Deny"

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, permission-denied

In my app, I'm accessing the phone contacts. So I'm handling the permission for the same in Android marshmallow devices. The permission dialog shows up as expected. Problem : Whenever I click on Deny button of the dialog, the dialog is not getting dismissed. 
Here's my code:

```
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;
String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,,Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS};
```

In Activity onCreate:

```
if(!requestPermissionForContact(this, PERMISSIONS)){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CurrentActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
}
else{
    getContactList(); //a method to accesses the contacts
}
```

requestPermissionForContact method definition :

```
public boolean requestPermissionForContact(Context context,String... permissions){
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(EmergencyContact.this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)){
                    //Toast.makeText(this,"You gotta allow permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Inside onRequestPermissionResult :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    //mPresenter.userRespondedForPermissionDialog(requestCode,REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS,grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS : {
            if (grantResults.length >= 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted , Access contacts here or do whatever you need.
                getContactList(); //Accessing the contacts
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Problem : The issue I'm facing is on the click of Deny, permission dialog is not getting dismissed. Please help. many Thanks in advance.

Device used to Test : OnePlus One with Android Marshmallow 6.0.1

Comment: there is no need to call `return`

Comment: @rookieDeveloper Ok.Removed it. No changes. The dialog still didnt get dismissed.

Comment: i have posted the answer, check if you can use it

Comment: @rookieDeveloper I'm currently working on it. I'll let you know.Thanks!

Comment: @rookieDeveloper, May I know what's this REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS?

Comment: @rookieDeveloper, I tried with the solution you provided. Even then the Permission dialog isn't getting dismissedon the click of "Deny", though the toast shows up.

Comment: is it working fine for allow?

Comment: @rookieDeveloper Yes it does work well for allow even before.

Comment: Guys, any update on this?

Comment: have you checked on any other device?

Comment: @rookieDeveloper I haven't checked on any other device. Could it be device specific issue?

Answer (score 3):

The issue I had was on the click of Deny button, the same activity was getting loaded again, which causes the permission dialogue to appear again.

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer. It is the OP explaining what caused the problem.